# method to output stdin AND stdout in the output

Tags: shell, stdout, stdin

I need a simple way to capture both the issued command (from a script) and the resultant output to a log file.

Here's a simple example:
Command:

```
grep '^#PermitRootLogin' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Output:

```
#PermitRootLogin no
```

Required result:

```
grep '^#PermitRootLogin' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  PermitRootLogin no
```

By redirecting stdin I seem to be stomping on stdout; it shouldn't be so difficult but it's eluding me for some reason.

Using tee just creates a log file with extraneous noise; and I'd like to use the file for a report at the end (no noise).

Thanks in advance,

TT

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your desired behaviour in a function, i.e.

```
function stomp {
    echo $@
    eval $@
}
```

then call it like so

```
stomp grep '^#PermitRootLogin' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the `script` utility, that will record everything you type plus what any program outputs to stdout in a file named `typescript`. However, it is *very* thorough and also records all the newlines and line feeds plus all the prompts by the shell, so most likely you want to post process the `typescript`.

Maybe it's easier to just

```
echo "grep '^#PermitRootLogin' /etc/ssh/sshd_config" > file
grep '^#PermitRootLogin' /etc/ssh/sshd_config >> file
```

Then you have the command and its output in `file`.

Comment: I thought of that but it's a lot of duplication. It's quick and dirty but I was hoping for something more elegant.